# analyze windows vs c++ project in sonarqube

Tags: visual-c++, sonarqube

I have installed sonarqube 6.4 on ubuntu 16.4 following this guideline https://www.google.com/search?ei=pjufWsm0BMKl0gTaiYawDQ&q=how+to+uninstall+sonarqube+on+ubuntu&oq=how+to+uninstall+sonarqube+on+ubuntu&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1248446.1248649.0.1249351.2.2.0.0.0.0.308.308.3-1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.r9CK_5NV4BE.
i am googleing about how to analyze windows vs c++ project using sonarqube server, yet find no thing useful. it seems that i need to install sonarqube server on windows specifically to do this specific windows vs c++ project, am i right?

Comment: forget about my asking, i guess sonarlint is my answer

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49075494/2662707) the languages/platforms are different, but the question is essentially the same.